# fgets malloc c help

Tags: c, malloc, fgets

if i have a variable from fgets

for example  fgets(question,200,stdin);
how do i determine the size of the variable question without all the trailing blank elemets?

Comment: Accept some answers man.

Comment: sorry i was checking if it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`strlen(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strlen.3.html). Was there a question about [`malloc(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/malloc.3.html) too?

Comment: thanks alot no i had just forgotten strlen i was trying sizeof(...)

Comment: In that case `fgets` won't cut it at all.